# Measurement of CPU cycles with perf

Tags: linux, performance, cpu, perf, cpu-cycles

Currently I'm working on measuring the time of code execution.

I can measure how much time took to execute function (using tracepoints) but I also need to measure how many cpu cycles the execution of funcB took, and it would be good to know how perf measured the time I got (is it a simple diff of unix time, or does it really use PMU counters)..

I would be very grateful for your help.

I have created a simple .c program which has a function that is called twenty times, and this function has a delay of about 1 second.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void funcB(int l){
    usleep(1000*l);
    printf("l=%d\n", l);
}

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
      printf("i=%d\n", i);
      funcB(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this file with g flag (to include debugging info)
Then I used perf probe to create tracepoints at funcB entry and funcB return.
Then I ran perf record including those events (**perf record -e $funcb_probe -e $funcb_ret_probe ./test**), and then dumped data from perf script (**perf script --ns -F time,event --deltatime**), and then decoded it with my python script.

*(--deltatime: used to measure time difference between events, -F time,event : used to make dumped file easier to decode)*

And I can plot the execution time of funcB.

**UPDATE 29/04/2023**

Tu visualise problem i have two graphs (both execute selection sort with 10k data) (.c file updated)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insertionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;
        
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

void funcB(int arr[], int n){
    insertionSort(arr, n);
}

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        int arr[10000];

        for (int f = 0; f < 10000 ;f++) {
            arr[f] = (rand() % 1000);
        }
        int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
        printf("i=%d\n", i);
        funcB(arr, n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This one is without CPU stress:
[image: Without CPU stress (peaks are still visible)]

And this with CPU stress:
[image: With CPU stress (CPU stress is visible from tracepoit 0 to ca. 110)]

So, increased CPU usage is visible on the graph (i.e. my function execution time has increased), my question is, is it possible to measure the exact time my function takes (independent of CPU usage), or is it possible to know how many CPU cycles my function took to execute (which should be independent of CPU usage)?

Comment: _it would be good to know how perf measured the time_ - The [Perf Wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) says: _… a tool for using the performance counters … Performance counters are CPU hardware registers …_

Comment: @Armali: `perf stat` and `perf record` with the default `-e cycles` event use hardware performance-counter events, but this question is about recording timestamps at tracepoints.

Comment: I don't think the hardware PMU supports generating a sample at a hardware "breakpoint" (code address), so I assume tracepoints work basically like breakpoints that log a timestamp in software.  Perhaps with `rdtsc`, but it's remotely possible they could use `rdpmc` to snapshot counters for other events at a tracepoint so you could maybe get an interval in core clock cycles instead of something wall-clock-equivalent like TSC ticks.   (For well over a decade, x86 CPUs have had the `constant_tsc` feature which means it ticks at its own fixed rate, not core clocks, allowing cheap clock_gettime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can measure CPU cycles, issued instructions and other hardware events supported by the PMU. The kernel automatically re-configures the PMU when rescheduling your process, so events from other processes are not counted.

With tracepoints, you can use *group leader sampling:*

```
perf record -e '{probe_a:funcB,cycles:u}:S'
```

This adds PMU event `cycles` counting only in userspace (`:u`) to the counter group and enables leader sampling (`:S`) so that when sampling the leader (here the uprobe tracepoint `probe_a:funcB`) values of both counters are recorded. See [`perf help list`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-list.1.html) for more information about event specification syntax.

Alternatively, you can use the [`perf_event_open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) syscall to configure and retrieve PMU counters directly from C code. Depending on your circumstances, this may have the following advantages:

- will not require elevated privileges for configuring tracepoints;
- has very low overhead (about 30-50 cycles if you invoke the `read` syscall directly) that you can measure and subtract;
- helps understanding how the `perf` tool works.

The `perf_event_open` man page offers a [short example](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html#EXAMPLES) that demonstrates how to read a single counter. For reading multiple counters, you can add them in a group and retrieve them with a single `read` syscall: they will be frozen on privilege change (if configured with `.ignore_kernel = 1`), making the read-out atomic.